# Como percorrer um iterable?

Tags: java

Tenho um método *keysWithPrefix* com o propósito de retornar todas as keys que começam com um valor de entrada que é especificado como na implementação abaixo:

```
    public Iterable<String> keysWithPrefix(String pre) {
      Queue<String> q = new Queue<String>() {
      collect(get(root, pre, 0), pre, q);
      return q;
   }
   private void collect(Node x, String pre, Queue<String> q) {
      if (x == null) return;
      if (x.val != null) q.add(pre);
      for (char c = 0; c < R; c++)
         collect(x.next[c], pre + c, q);
   }
```

Mas não sei como imprimir o retorno na tela. Esse metodo retorna um Iterable de string

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que dê pra fazer de duas formas;

**1ª Opção**

```
Iterable<String> keys = keysWithPrefix(pre);
Iterator<String> it = keys.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
   System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

**2ª Opção**

```
Iterable<String> keys = keysWithPrefix(pre);
for(String key: keys){
   System.out.println(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para percorrer um `Iterable` e imprimir o seu valor você pode fazer assim:

```
Iterable<String> iterable = keysWithPrefix(pre);    
Iterable<String> q = iterable.iterator();
//verifica se existe itens a percorrer no Iterable
while(q.hasNext()) {
    //pega um item do Iterable
    String item = q.next();
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

Se você estiver usando o java 8 você pode fazer:

```
Iterable<String> iterable = keysWithPrefix(pre);
//imprime o valor usando o foreach
iterable.foreach(item -> {
    String item = q.next();
    System.out.println(item);
});
//funciona dessa forma também
iterable.foreach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Eu creio que você confundiu com [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)

Comment: Eu esqueci de colocar o método que chama o `iterator`, obrigado @JeffersonQuesado, já fiz o ajuste.